# Comparar usando compareTo

Tags: java

Tengo que ordenar las impresiones por color, grosor y tapa. Se tienen que hacer 100 impresiones, de manera aleatoria, con los elementos de la lista; el problema que tengo está en ordenarlos por el orden en el que deben aparecer en la lista: Si los colores son iguales, comparar la tapa y si es igual comparar por grosor. En el atributo de grosor solo se me permiten valores de (5-1), ordenar el grosor de menor a mayor

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        **String[] colores= {"AZUL","AMARILLO","CAFE","PURPURA","ROSA"};
        String[] tapa={"SI","NO"};
        int grosor;
        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i=0; i<100;i++) {
        int n =rand.nextInt(5);
        int z =rand.nextInt(2);
        grosor=(rand.nextInt(5-1+1)+1);

        String m= colores[n];
        String j=tapa[z];

        System.out.println(" COLOR: " + m  +""+"         \n TAPA:"+j+"\n GROSOR:"+grosor+"\n");
        } 
    }
```

Clase Marcador:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class Marcador {
    static class ordenador implements Comparable <ordenador> {
    private final String color;
    private final String tapa;
    private final int grosor;

    public ordenador(String color,String tapa,int grosor){
        this.color=color;
        this.tapa=tapa;
        this.grosor=grosor;

    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ordenador o){
        if (color.compareTo(o.color)<0)
          return 1;
        else if(color.compareTo(o.color)>0)
            return -1;
        else 
            return 0;
    } 

     static void imprimeArraycolores(ordenador[] array){
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
        int n =rand.nextInt(4);
           System.out.println((i+1)+"."+array[i].color);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] colores= {"AZUL","AMARILLO","CAFE","PURPURA"};

        System.out.println("SIN ORDENAR");
        imprimeArraycolores(colores);
        Arrays.sort(colores);
        System.out.println("CON ORDEN");
        imprimeArraycolores(colores);

        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

de una manera rapida se me ocurre de esta manera

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] colores= {"AZUL","AMARILLO","CAFE","PURPURA","ROSA"};
        String[] tapa={"SI","NO"};
        int grosor;
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Marcador> listFinal = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Marcador> listaAzul = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Marcador> listaAmarillo = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Marcador> listacafe = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Marcador> listaPurpura = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Marcador> listaRosa = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
            int n =rand.nextInt(5);
            int z =rand.nextInt(2);
            grosor=(rand.nextInt(5-1+1)+1);

            String m= colores[n];
            String j=tapa[z];
            Marcador marcador = new Marcador(m,j,grosor);


            if(marcador !=null ){
                if("AZUL".equals(marcador.getColor())){
                    listaAzul.add(marcador);

                }else if("AMARILLO".equals(marcador.getColor())){
                    listaAmarillo.add(marcador);
                }else if("CAFE".equals(marcador.getColor())){
                    listacafe.add(marcador);
                }else if("PURPURA".equals(marcador.getColor())){
                    listaPurpura.add(marcador);
                }else if("ROSA".equals(marcador.getColor())){
                    listaRosa.add(marcador);
                }
            }

        } 
        Collections.sort(listaAzul);
        Collections.sort(listaAmarillo);
        Collections.sort(listaAmarillo);
        Collections.sort(listacafe);
        Collections.sort(listaPurpura);
        Collections.sort(listaRosa);
        listFinal.addAll(listaAzul);
        listFinal.addAll(listaAmarillo);
        listFinal.addAll(listacafe);
        listFinal.addAll(listaPurpura);
        listFinal.addAll(listaRosa);
        for (Marcador marcador : listFinal) {
            System.out.println(" COLOR: " + marcador.getColor()  +""+"         \n TAPA:"+marcador.getTapa()+"\n GROSOR:"+marcador.getGrosor()+"\n");
        }
    }


el objecto marcador
```

package testWS;

```
public class Marcador     {

    private  String color;
    private  String tapa;
    private  int grosor;


    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public String getTapa() {
        return tapa;
    }
    public void setTapa(String tapa) {
        this.tapa = tapa;
    }
    public int getGrosor() {
        return grosor;
    }
    public void setGrosor(int grosor) {
        this.grosor = grosor;
    }

    public Marcador (String color,String tapa,int grosor){
        this.color=color;
        this.tapa=tapa;
        this.grosor=grosor;

    }

 @Override
 public int compareTo(Marcador o) {
     if("SI".equals(o.getTapa())){

     if (grosor < o.grosor) {
         return -1;
     }
     if (grosor > o.grosor) {
         return 1;
     }
     }
     return -2;
 }

}
```

lo que me falto por tiempo porque voy saliendo, es ordenar por grosor esto lo puedes hacer con el metodo compareTo, tendrias que aplicarlo unas vez que tienes las lista por colores.

saludos

la salida por pantalla

COLOR: AZUL
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:5

COLOR: AZUL
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:5

COLOR: AZUL
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:1

COLOR: AZUL
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:4

COLOR: AZUL
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:1

COLOR: AZUL
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:5

COLOR: AZUL
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:3

COLOR: AZUL
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:5

COLOR: AZUL
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:5

COLOR: AMARILLO
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: AMARILLO
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:3

COLOR: AMARILLO
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:4

COLOR: AMARILLO
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:5

COLOR: AMARILLO
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:4

COLOR: AMARILLO
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:4

COLOR: AMARILLO
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:4

COLOR: AMARILLO
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:4

COLOR: AMARILLO
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: CAFE
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:4

COLOR: CAFE
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: CAFE
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: CAFE
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:1

COLOR: CAFE
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: CAFE
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:4

COLOR: CAFE
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:1

COLOR: CAFE
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: CAFE
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:3

COLOR: CAFE
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:1

COLOR: CAFE
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:5

COLOR: PURPURA
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:1

COLOR: PURPURA
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: PURPURA
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:3

COLOR: PURPURA
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: PURPURA
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: PURPURA
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:3

COLOR: PURPURA
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:5

COLOR: PURPURA
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:5

COLOR: PURPURA
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:5

COLOR: PURPURA
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:4

COLOR: ROSA
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:1

COLOR: ROSA
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:1

COLOR: ROSA
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: ROSA
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: ROSA
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: ROSA
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:2

COLOR: ROSA
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:4

COLOR: ROSA
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:5

COLOR: ROSA
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:3

COLOR: ROSA
 TAPA:SI
 GROSOR:5

COLOR: ROSA
 TAPA:NO
 GROSOR:3

Comment: Buen día, ya probé el código y únicamente se ordena por color, no se toma en cuenta si tiene tapa para ser ordenado; cuando los colores son iguales

Comment: Si, si deje ese comentario en el post, por falta de tiempo no pude terminar la otra parte.

Ahora deje el codigo completo con lo que necesitas, estaba muy avanzado, como sugerencia no esperes que te hagan las tareas pon de tu parte.

ademas agradecer no cuesta nada.

Saludos.

Comment: De antemano te pido una disculpa y te agradezco por tomarte el tiempo para responder mi duda. Saludos

Comment: Hola Pedro, te sirvió la respuesta, es lo que esperabas ??